# How to create a shared object among all the requests?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core

I am beginner in backend development. I have a simple .Net Core Web API application. I want to store an integer to count the called request amount .

So every enpoint call, I increment 1 the `counter`.  But the `counter` reinitalized every request with 0 because of the constructor call.  How can I create a shared `counter` among the all requests so that I count the called request amount.

My simplified class is this:

```
[ApiController]
[Route("/")]
public class WeatherForecastController : ControllerBase
{
   DataContext _context;
   int counter ;
   public WeatherForecastController(DataContext context){
        counter = 0;  //initialized with 0
        _context = context;
    }


    [HttpGet]
    public string Get()
    {
        counter++; //every time 0 to 1
        .....
        .....
    }

    [HttpPost(".....")]
    public async Task UploadFile([FromForm] string ...)
    {
        counter++; //every time 0 to 1
        .....
        .....
    }


    [HttpGet("....")]
    public string Get2(string ...)
    {
        counter++; //every time 0 to 1
        .....
        .....
    }

    [HttpPost(".....")]
    public async Task Post4([FromForm] string ...)
    {
        counter++; //every time 0 to 1
        .....
        .....
    }
```

}

Comment: by the way why are you hitting the server just to get the count? why dont you implement on client side?

Comment: Because I need to know this counter for all client, not only one client.

Answer (score 3):

I think the following code can help you, You can do this by defining a variable as static

```
[ApiController]
[Route("/")]
public class WeatherForecastController : ControllerBase
{
  DataContext _context;
  static int counter = 0;
  public WeatherForecastController(DataContext context){
    _context = context;
  }


  [HttpGet]
  public string Get()
  {
    counter++; 
  }

  [HttpPost("UploadFile")]
  public async Task UploadFile()
  {
    counter++;
  }
}
```

Comment: Is this thread safe? What happens when two request access the counter and increment it at the same time?

Comment: when call the functions from a shared object may solve

Answer (score 0):

The main issue is how the Controllers themselves work.

The Controllers life span is only when the request is made then they are disposed of as far as i am aware.

IE: When a request is made to /api/controller a new instance is spun up to deal with the request then disposed of.

What you're looking to do is keep some form of persistence. What I would recommend is either having a logging tool that you would inject into the controller that logs that it has been accessed then you can extract the amount of times its been called from that.
Or have a model in your Context that you just update whenever a call is made to the controller.

Both of these are thread safe in comparison to just sticking a static variable in it

Comment: I didn't understand the first option. Could you give an example for first option?  Also , in option 2 you mean that should I use the database?